# how to get the time from this format "Tue Jun 09 18:45:00 IST 2015" in postgresql store procedures

Tags: scala, postgresql-9.4

I am using the following query to get day:

select  to_char(CAST ("COLUMN_NAME" AS DATE), 'DY') from TABLE_NAME

How can I get the time component?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

postgres=# create table test_tim(tim  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE);

CREATE TABLE

postgres=# insert into test_tim values(current_timestamp);

INSERT 0 1

postgres=# select to_char(tim,'HH24:MI:SS') from test_tim;

15:56:00
(1 row)